# How to adjust the size of a Launchrock-widget?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm running a Joomla website, and am trying to embed a launcrock-widget (launchrock is a service that lets people interested in your project enter their email, so when you're done you can email them), but I can't really adjust the size of it. The widget comes in 1 line of javascript code that I put in a Joomla article using the Sourcerer Code Helper plugin.

The widget is embedded here:
http://cavemanskin.com/index.php/14-day-meal-plan-widget

Now there are 2 problems: for some reason 1) the widget takes up the whole page and 2) the grey box under the text is gone so you can't really read it.
With 'inspect element I noticed that Launchrock puts everything in a DIV named 'lr-widget'. 
I added the code:

```
<style type="text/css">  
div#lr-widget { height:300px; width:300px }  
</style>
```

But the widget is still the same size.
Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: the code of the widget only works on the domain that I gave launchrock, I'd like to experiment with a .html on my PC with the javascript code in it but the launchrock widget doesn't load at all.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this in Chrome developer there is an inner shell that can also be customized and added in your master css so overwrite their classes and added to your Master CSS.

EX:

```
.LR-content {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 200px;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.LR-bg-img {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #222222;
    background-image: url("img/classicBg.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    content: "";
    height: 50%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

I was just testing those and you can see the many changes. So you can try grabing those codes and overwrite them on your master.

Comment: Wow it already looks very different now. But what is an 'inner shell' here? And what is exactly happening with those changes you suggested? You made a new class for the background image, but Ctrl-F for bg-img in the page source code doens't give any results, so is the class really used somewhere?

Comment: Do you use Chrome Developer Debugger tool(F12)? or Firebug? thats where i got the classes on their css...obviously I was just messing around with the sizes. With Chromes debugger tool you can actually edit from there and make your desire.... from the looks of it LaunchRock add this *.LR-bg-img* for the wrapper shell...I'm not sure how your intentions and placements are going but this is how i started to see the changes.

Comment: I use chrome - just now found that you can acces the CSS with the sources tab. Thanks for the suggestion to change the code in Chrome Debugger: it is much faster than changing the inline style sheet in the Joomla article editor. I'm starting to understand this CSS concept I think. Now to get the box underneath the text back..

Comment: After playing around some more, and comparing the CSS code you pasted with the code from Launchrock, I really don't understand how the widget now occupies just a bit of the screen instead of the whole screen: you didn't seem to have changed the stack order (z), the positioning, or any of the background parameters...

Comment: As I mentioned I was only working with the shell that LR provides the idea is that you can overwrite their classes and make it as you desire